# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean: "DRAFT"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am doing a case statement like this

```
CASE coe_status
    WHEN 'PUBLISHED' THEN 'Published'
    WHEN 'DRAFT' AND 'REVIEW' THEN 'Open'
    ELSE 'No-Coes'
```

The issue I am encountering is that

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean: "DRAFT"
```

Is there not a way to combine these two so they can have one sum instead of having it like this

```
CASE coe_status
    WHEN 'PUBLISHED' THEN 'Published'
    WHEN 'DRAFT' THEN 'Open'
    WHEN 'REVIEW' THEN 'Open'
    ELSE 'No-Coes'
```

Comment: `'DRAFT' AND 'REVIEW'` is an expression. The AND means you are trying to treat both values as booleans and check if both are true. If you want to know the syntax of an expression check the manuals https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-conditional.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the simple form of the case expression, by which you can not use more than one condition for each `WHEN` clause.

Instead, you could use the general/ searched form of the case expression as the following:

```
CASE 
  WHEN coe_status = 'PUBLISHED' THEN 'Published'
  WHEN coe_status ='DRAFT' OR coe_status ='REVIEW' THEN 'Open' -- Or simply use, WHEN coe_status IN ('DRAFT', 'REVIEW') THEN 'Open'
  ELSE 'No-Coes'
END
```

Comment: The issue with this is that wouldn't it pull out this error
`RROR: operator does not exist: character varying = boolean Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 200`

Comment: Ahh i figured it out i was doing `CASE coe_status` instead of `CASE` on its own